# inputting json file from shell i converted using marshal the file but now i have to add metadata uuid and time

Tags: json, go

Im inputing JSON file from shell and converting to specific format i did that part on bottom but im trying to include like metadat like time ,uuid and couple of other thing to it  then printout the new json file.My issue i cant put the new info to data part of the data

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "time"
//      "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func help() {
        fmt.Println("help")
}

type Event struct{
        Specversion string               `json:"specversion"`
        ID          string              `json:"id"`   /// uuid
        Source      string              `json:"source"`
//      Type        bool                `json:"type"`
        Time        time.Now             `json:"time"`
        Data        string       `json:"data"`  /// this part supposed to come from the file
}

func main(){

        if len(os.Args) < 1 { //checking for provided argument if the first arg satisfy then use read file
                fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
                help()
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        out, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"data": string(file)})
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        //fmt.Println(string(out))


e := Event{
Specversion: "1.0",
//id: uuid.New(),
Source: "CSS",
//type: true,
Time: time.Now(),
Data: data.(string),
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
fmt.Println(string(e))
//fmt.Println(string(id))

}
```

The outcome should be this

```
{
  "specversion": "1.0",
  "id": "ce20b92d-b45b-hhd7-a544-8fe4d8f7ff06",
  "source": "CCS",
  "type": "EVENT",
  "time": "2022-08-09T23:59:08.468903+00:00",
  "data": "{\"mac_address\": null, \".................
```

original file from input

```
 "mac_address": "",
  "serial_number": "j",
  "device_type": "STORAGE",
  "device_model": "VIRTUAL",
  "part_number": "VIRTUAL",
  "extra_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_type": "ENTITLEMENT_ID",
      "attribute_value": "H6MI9JYNJCOSBL1GTjfgjfjY6P"
```

Comment: The code you provided does not compile, and I'm struggling to understand your approach, which makes this difficult to answer. I think you might be trying to something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/ksPo3P5QxPZ) (this will not provide the result you want - just trying to understand your requirement) - please use my code to demonstrate your issue, providing code that compiles/runs (but does not achieve your goal!) makes it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @Brits You kind of answered it i just want it to have in that format above. But i was hard time creating UUid for the id part.

Answer (score 0):

The application marshals a map with the data, but not the metadata.  The application configures a value with the metadata and data, but does nothing with it.  Pull those pieces together.  Something like this:

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
    os.Exit(1)
}

e := Event{
    Specversion: "1.0",
    Source: "CSS",
    Time: time.Now(),
    Data: string(file),
}

out, _ := json.MarshalIndent(e, "", "  ")
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

[Run the program on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4-3D8JxcWPR).

Comment: Since im inputing file how can i make argument in command line lets say i want pass two options -p or -u  that just print out -p=pass or  - u unpass for the metadata where its "type" on json file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach below for this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"
    //      "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func help() {
    fmt.Println("help")
}

type Event struct {
    Specversion string `json:"specversion"`
    ID          string `json:"id"` /// uuid
    Source      string `json:"source"`
    //      Type        bool                `json:"type"`
    Time time.Now               `json:"time"`
    Data map[string]interface{} `json:"data"` /// this part supposed to come from the file
}

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 1 { //checking for provided argument if the first arg satisfy then use read file
        fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
        help()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    res := map[string]interface{}{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(file, &res)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    e := Event{
        Specversion: "1.0",
        //id: uuid.New(),
        Source: "CSS",
        //type: true,
        Time: time.Now(),
        Data: res,
    }

    fmt.Println(e)

}
```

Defining your Event struct data type as map sting interface helps.
Hope this works.

Comment: @Roashan   your code has error :cannot convert res (type map[string]interface {}) to type string
and cannot convert e (type Event) to type string

Comment: @Amateur_ik the error was caused due to trying to pring event struct type in string. Kindly remove the string parse and try. I did updated the code please try again.